# Capture output from external command and write it to a file

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, svn, scripting

I am trying to create a script that calls on a linux command from my Ubuntu server and prints the output of aforementioned command to txt files.  This is literally the first script I've ever written, I just started learning python recently.  I want 3 files in 3 separate folders with filenames unique to date.

```
def swo():
        from subprocess import call
        call("svn info svn://url")

def tco():
        from subprocess import call
        call("svn info svn://url2")

def fco():
        from subprocess import call
        call("url3")

import time
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")

fs = "/path/1/" + timestr
ft = "/path/2/" + timestr
fc = "/path/3/" + timestr


f1 = open(fs + '.txt', 'w')
f1.write(swo)
f1.close()

f2 = open(ft + '.txt', 'w')
f2.write(tco)
f2.close()

f3 = open(fc + '.txt' 'w')
f3.write(fco)
f3.close()
```

It is failing at the f.write() functions.  I'm stuck at making the output of the linux commands the actual text in the new files.

Comment: `subprocess` can write command output directly to a file by passing an open file object to the `stdout` argument of the `call` function. https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: You may want to start by working through a [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/). None of your functions return a (useful) value, and you aren't calling them in the first place. (`tco()`, not `tco`).

Comment: Which is why I am here, trial by fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after all.  The following works great!

```
## This will get the last revision number overall in repository ##

import os
sfo = os.popen("svn info svn://url1 | grep Revision")
sfo_output = sfo.read()
tco = os.popen("svn info svn://url2 | grep Revision")
tco_output = tco.read()
fco = os.popen("svn://url3 | grep Revision")
fco_output = fco.read()




## This part imports the time function, and creates a variable that will be the ##
## save path of the new file which is than output in the f1, f2 and f3 sections ##

import time
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")

fs = "/root/path/" + timestr
ft = "/root/path/" + timestr
fc = "/root/path/" + timestr

f1 = open(fs + '-code-rev.txt', 'w')
f1.write(sfo_output)
f1.close()

f2 = open(ft + '-code-rev.txt', 'w')
f2.write(tco_output)
f2.close()

f3 = open(fc + '-code-rev.txt', 'w')
f3.write(fco_output)
f3.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this instead:

```
import time
import subprocess as sp
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")

fs = "/path/1/" + timestr
ft = "/path/2/" + timestr
fc = "/path/3/" + timestr


f1 = open(fs + '.txt', 'w')
rc = sp.call("svn info svn://url", stdout=f1, stderr=sp.STDOUT)
f1.close()

f2 = open(ft + '.txt', 'w')
rc = sp.call("svn info svn://url2", stdout=f2, stderr=sp.STDOUT)
f2.close()

f3 = open(fc + '.txt' 'w')
rc = sp.call("svn info svn://url3", stdout=f3, stderr=sp.STDOUT)
f3.close()
```

Assuming the `url3` command you used was supposed to be `svn info svn://url3`. This allows the `subprocess.call` to save command output directly to a file.